# adding texts to connector and adjusting texts to shapes using apache POI OOXML

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint, openxml, ecma

Recently I am working with Apache POI and i am facing an issues

I have  requirement to glue texts above rectangle to connector by using Apache POI/OOXML as below, as per OOXML specification texts can not be set to connectors.is there any way can we glue texts like below without using text boxes by using APACHE POI OOXML, appreciate your help.

[texts to connectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16GIp.png)

while adding texts to shapes, when shape size is large it is visible clearly, some times shape size can be reduced/increased dynamically, in that case,  can we autofit to show text in smaller sizes clearly in shape .we need to auto resize texts based on shape size dynamically.

[adding texts to shapes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xzfdm.png)

appreciate help

as per OOXML specification texts can not be set to connectors.is there any way can we glue texts like below without using text boxes by using APACHE POI OOXML, appreciate your help.

while adding texts to shapes, when shape size is large it is visible clearly, some times shape size can be reduced/increased dynamically, in that case can we autofit to show text in smaller sizes clearly in shape. we need to auto resize texts based on shape size dynamically.

Comment: Please take the time to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). This is a question/answer site. Means: **One** question - multiple answers. Best answer gets most up votes. You are asking two different questions here. This is not how this site works.

Comment: To your first question: How would you do this using PowerPoint GUI? Apache POI cannot do what Microsoft Office is not able to do.

Comment: To your second question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69346748/shrink-text-on-overflow-on-a-shape-in-power-point/69351702#69351702

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.